# Error running Electron

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I succesfully had the electron GUI running for testing my app, including the electron hello world application that they have here: http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/

Now however whenever I type the command: `npm start` in the command line I get this error (even when just trying to set up the hello world example again):

```
12 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v4.4.4
15 error npm  v2.15.1
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start: `electron main.js`
17 error Exit status 3221225781
18 error Failed at the electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start script 'electron main.js'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the electron-quick-start package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     electron main.js
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs electron-quick-start
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls electron-quick-start
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Also one instance of an electron app I set up previously still works when I call `npm start`.

I would like to be able to setup new apps, partially because my original one doesn't have the correct folder structure.

---

So using `npm list --depth 1` I went to both the folders with both the working electron app, and the not working electron app. Both show `electron-prebuilt@1.1.0` as being present. Although using `npm list -g` shows that electron-prebuilt is not installed globally, perhaps that would be a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update Electron to `v1.1.1` (`npm install electron-prebuilt@latest --save-dev`) and that should hopefully solve your issue (which is probably that you're missing the VC++2015 runtime). Installing `electron-prebuilt` globally isn't going to fix anything.

Comment: After looking everywhere that was the solution on my case.